# Serialize Array into elements, transform using RxJS, and assemble elements back to array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, rxjs, rxjs5

In Angular2, I have a lot of `Observable<any[]>` (Observable that emits arrays) that offspring in `http.get()` or are feed via websocket operations and hence **do not .complete()** but emit multiple values over time.

Very often I need to transform the elements within the array with RxJS operators (I don't want to use Array.prototype.* transforms!) and assemble the individual elements back to an array, that is emitted as single entity.

But I don't know how to assemble the elements back to an array.

Example:

```
const n$ = new Subject();

const output = n$
    // create an observable emitting the individual elements
    // of the array
    .mergeMap(n => n)

    // some kind of transform on the elements
    .distinct((n1, n2) => n1 == n2)
    .map(n => n*n)

    // how to assemble back to an array here???
    // not working:
    // .buffer(n$)
    // also not working (subject does not complete!)
    // .toArray()

output.subscribe(v => console.log(v))

n$.next([1,1,1,2,3]);
n$.next([4,5,5,6]);

// Wanted output:
// [1, 4, 9]
// [16, 25, 36]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have multiple values and want a single value (the array), <s>`reduce`</s>`toArray` should be what you're after:

```
Rx.Observable.from([0, 1, 1, 2, 3])
    .distinct()
    .map((n) => n * n)
    // .reduce((acc, n) => { acc.push(n); return acc; }, [])
    .toArray()
    .subscribe((a) => { console.log(a); })
```

If you have an `Observable<any[]>`, just put it into in a `mergeMap`:

```
const output = n$
    .mergeMap((a) => Rx.Observable.from(a)
        .distinct()
        .map((n) => n * n)
        // .reduce((acc, n) => { acc.push(n); return acc; }, [])
        .toArray()
    )
    .subscribe(a => { console.log(a); });
```

Comment: You completely missed my main point: The Subject in my example __does not complete__, hence you need some sort of stop criterion in reduce(). Your example uses Rx.Observable.from() which _will complete_ - in this case `.toArray()` would also work.

Comment: No, I did see that. Unless I'm totally mistaken - which is possible! - the second snippet should be open ended - it's only the inner observable that completes - in which case, you are right: use `toArray` on the inner observable.

Comment: You are right, the second snippet works for open-ended observables, I am so sorry! Just for reference: the .distinct() function has a mandatory first argument which must be a selector function; using it as I originally put it in my example works.